# Server Manager Issues

Tags: .net, iis

I am trying to Access the ApplicationPools under IIS7.0 using the ServerManager

but i am getting an exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' if i try to access any fields of the server manager object even though i am logged in with the administrator account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen this specific issue but I'd look at the credentials the IIS service is running under.  It's possible it's got a custom windows account which you haven't got access to.